# Argument does not match prototype in C

Tags: c, function, prototype

Im supposed to write a code for a grocery store inventory that does a calculation in a separate function. Ive ran the code without the function and everything runs fine but as soon as I add the function I run into trouble. I keep getting the error telling me:

c:55:6: error: argument ‘b’ doesn’t match prototype
c:3:6: error: prototype declaration

I've tried playing around with the values I'm passing through the functions but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm fairly new with arrays so I could be missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void value_calc(int, float);

int main(){

        int barcode[100], quantity[100], i;
        double price[100], value[100], value1;


                printf("Grocery Store Inventory\n");
                printf("=======================\n");

        for(i=0;i<100;i++){

                printf("Barcode   :  ");

                        scanf("%d", &barcode[i]);

        if (barcode[i]==0){

                break;

        }

                printf("Price     :  ");
                        scanf("%lf", &price[i]);

                printf("Quantity  :  ");
                        scanf("%d", &quantity[i]);

        value_calc(quantity[i],price[i]);

        }


                printf("\n             Goods in Stock\n");
                printf("             ==============\n\n");

                printf("Barcode    Price    Quantity    Value\n");

                printf("-------------------------------------\n");

        for(i=0;i<100 && barcode[i] !=0;i++){


                printf("%d  %.2lf    %8d     %.2lf\n", barcode[i], price[i], quantity[i]);

        }

return 0;

        }

void value_calc(a,b){

        double value1;

        value1 = a*b;


        }
```

Comment: Why all the blank lines?

Comment: What is `value_calc()` supposed to do anyway? It returns nothing and has no side effects (even if you could decide on whether you wanted the second argument to be a double or a float)

Comment: `void value_calc(a,b) {...` should be `void value_calc(int a, float b) {...`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your definition of `value_calc` is omitting argument types:

```
void value_calc(int, float);

void value_calc(a,b) {
  ..
}
```

C allows you to omit argument types but they become `int` by default (enable being warned about it with `-Wimplicit-int` on GCC and Clang). Now you have a declaration with `int, float` and a definition with `int, int`, which doesn't match. Try with:

```
void value_calc(int a, float b) {
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The declaration

```
void value_calc(int, float);
```

does not match the function itself:

```
void value_calc(a,b)
...
```

because by default all function arguments are `int`. Use the same declaration in your function as in the declaration itself:

```
void value_calc (int a, float b)
...
```

Note: I also get a warning on this line, and you should look into it:

```
<stdin>:46:50: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
            printf("%d  %.2lf    %8d     %.2lf\n", barcode[i], price[i], quantity[i]);
```